# How reload Notepad++ without press enter sometimes

Tags: notepad++

My scripts write to a logfile. Its opened in Notepad++ to see any new content. 
its reloads automatically (if it gots focus again).
But sometimes then i got the message:
"your file is open in another program would you reload it"
i always press enter.
Is there a way to refresh always without to press enter sometimes?

Notepad++ v7.5.4   (64-bit)
Build time : Jan  1 2018 - 01:50:29
Path : C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Admin mode : ON
Local Conf mode : OFF
OS : Windows 10 (64-bit)
Plugins : DSpellCheck.dll mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll

[image]
[image]

Comment: Build time : Aug 29 2017 - 02:38:44
Notepad++ v7.5.1 - german version

Comment: There should be an option in Settings to always reload silently. If, after that, it still asks for reload, then it is a bug on the NP++ and you should report it to the project maintainers.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Now it happened again. Not yesterday. I use it every minute several times at the time. Today I added two screenshots. So, as you say, I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: thats the bugReport: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are too lazy to go look on GitHub for an answer:
Settings -> Preferences -> MISC. -> Update silently